# Can not install NumPy using pip in Python3, Ubuntu14.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, ssl, pip

I'm getting this error when trying pip install NumPy:

pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

```
Collecting numpy

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: 

Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Please provides `pip version` with command: `pip -V`

Comment: try to install libssl-dev with apt-get ...

Comment: @vanloc pip 9.0.1 from /home/nguyennguyenquochuy/tutorial-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

Comment: @GerardRozsavolgyi it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**:
Maybe try with `sudo -E`:

```
 -E          The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the secu‐
             rity policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing
             environment variables.  The security policy may return an
             error if the -E option is specified and the user does not
             have permission to preserve the environment.
```

**Solution 2**: proxy can be the affect to that. So:

```
sudo pip --proxy=http://username:password@proxyURL:portNumber install your-package
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have one issue or two:

First you need to install OpenSSL with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

Second make sure your python versions compiled against SSL. I believe you installed a precompiled version. In that case it will be fine. Otherwise you will need to install libssl-dev too before building your python

Comment: i installed libssl-dev and openssl before, but when i try to use pip install numpy , it's still not working.